# Remove an option from a Zend Radio Form Element

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

An easy question.
I have a Zend_Form_Element_Radio element in my form with multioptions.
I'd like to remove an option in my controller.

I've found how to disable an option ...

```
$element = $membershipForm->getElement('myElement');
$element->setAttrib('disable', array('value'));
```

But how can I remove it?
With removing some decorators? Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since every FormElement has a unique identifier it is pretty simply to remove it.

```
$form->removeElement($id); // most likely when removing from within the controller
$this->removeElement($id); // when removing from within the form object
$selectElement->removeMultiOption('value'); // To remove a single option from a select
```

That's all you need ;)

Comment: My goal is to remove an option from the multioptions array for a radio form element. removeElement($id) does the trick for the whole element, but i just want to remove 1 option from the element! Tnx anyway.

Comment: Oh, OK sry, then its `$selectElement->removeMultiOption('value');`

Comment: Removing by value did not work for me. I had to remove by key.